# Delete item from Client Object Model

Tags: client-object-model, list-item

I'm trying to delete an Item from a list using the following code:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using SP = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;

namespace Microsoft.SDK.SharePointServices.Samples
{
class DeleteListItem
{
    static void Main()
    {   
        string siteUrl = "http://MyServer/sites/MySiteCollection";

        ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
        SP.List oList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Announcements");
        ListItem oListItem = oList.GetItemById(2);

        oListItem.DeleteObject();

        clientContext.ExecuteQuery(); 
    }
}
```

}

for any item Id I try to delete, I  always get the same  message :

> Item does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user.

Comment: are you sure that you have access to the item?

Comment: With the same code trying to add or get a item I can access to.

Comment: Your code works perfectly for me. There must be a simple mismatch some place.

Comment: Just something I noticed: Why have you declared Microsoft.SharePoint.Client twice in the usings section?

Answer (score 4):

Try something like:

```
string siteUrl = "http://MyServer/sites/MySiteCollection";

ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
SP.List oList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Announcements");

clientContext.Load(oList);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery()

ListItem oListItem = oList.GetItemById(2);

clientContext.Load(oListItem);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

oListItem.DeleteObject();

clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

This worked for me...

Comment: Even if the question and answer are old... there is no need to load list and item before the delete, the code in the question is correct.

Answer (score 1):

The important thing is to **NOT** call Load in the same "ExecuteQuery-Cycle" as you call DeleteObject (or Recycle). You have to split the operation in two and call ExecuteQuery twice:

```
var item = customList.GetItemById(24);
ctx.Load(item);
ctx.ExecuteQuery(); //Perform Webservice Call to Get Item

item.Recycle();
ctx.ExecuteQuery(); //Perform Webservice Call to Delete Item
```